# Solving a system of polynomial equation - can I trust numerical results?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, systems-of-equations, computational-algebra, groebner-basis

To finish a proof, I need to solve a system of two polynomials with integer coefficients in two variables, $\{F_1(x,y)=0,\,F_2(x,y)=0\}$, and then show that no solutions satisfy $0<x<1$ and $y>0$, where $F_1,F_2$ are as follows:

$$ \begin{equation*} \begin{split}
F_1(x,y) &= -168 x^{11} - 1386 x^{10} y + x^9 (730 - 420 y^2) - 9 x^8 y (-489 + 370 y^2) + 14 x^6 y (-135 + 256 y^2 + 6 y^4) \\
&+ 6 x^2 y^5 (747 - 282 y^2 + 29 y^4) - 8 x^3 y^4 (513 + 209 y^2 + 39 y^4) - 16 x^7 (45 - 26 y^2 + 72 y^4) + y^7 (270 + 79 y^2 + 78 y^4) \\
&+ 30 x^4 y^3 (-249 - 38 y^2 + 138 y^4) - 2 x y^6 (-1134 + 67 y^2 + 186 y^4) - 12 x^5 y^2 (171 - 363 y^2 + 298 y^4)\\ 
&\\ 
F_2(x,y) &= -126 x^{11} - 84 x^{10} y + x^9 (489 - 1110 y^2) - 
 8 x^8 y (-13 + 72 y^2) + 12 y^7 (216 - 65 y^2 + 4 y^4) \\
&+ 6 x^7 (-45 + 256 y^2 + 10 y^4) - 12 x^4 y^3 (342 + 209 y^2 + 52 y^4) + 
 6 x^3 y^4 (1245 - 658 y^2 + 87 y^4) \\
&+  3 x y^6 (630 + 237 y^2 + 286 y^4) - 12 x^6 y (57 - 242 y^2 + 298 y^4) - 4 x^2 y^5 (-1701 + 134 y^2 + 465 y^4) \\
&+ 6 x^5 y^2 (-747 - 190 y^2 + 966 y^4) 
\end{split} \end{equation*}$$

I've used Mathematica to compute the solutions and find that my claim is true. I understand that Mathematica's algorithm to solve these systems is based on Grobner basis but unfortunately I lack the background necessary to understand them well. My questions are:

1. **Can I trust that Mathematica correctly finds all the real solutions to the system?**
2. If so, what theoretical results ensure that all the solutions to the system can be computed via these algorithms?

Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: That theory has been around for a long time and I cannot imagine there is an issue. Implementations can be faulty. Can you also use Mathematica's numerical routine that finds all roots and then get another opinion using SAGE or Matlab or another CAS as a comparison point?

Comment: This may be more appropriate at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thanks @Moo - Yes, I checked in Sage and got the same solutions. I learned a bit more about the theory on Grobner basis and now understand more about the theory, so I'm confident on the results.

Comment: And Thanks @KReiser - I've also posted it in the mathematica stackexchange, but wanted to learn about the underlying theory as well.